# Not able to get ads from admob with mopub

Tags: android, admob, ads, mopub

I've been trying to get ads running on my app for a couple of days now. I have everything setup, line item, banner, admob ID (the one with ca-app....), I got the right mopub Id and everything. However I still get this message:

```
12-16 20:13:44.984    2778-2778/com.spekz D/skia﹕ GFXPNG PNG bitmap created       width:720 height:279 bitmap id is 184
12-16 20:13:44.994    2778-2778/com.spekz D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 55K, 18% free 27700K/33472K, paused 14ms, total 14ms
12-16 20:13:45.004    2778-2778/com.spekz I/dalvikvm-heap﹕ Grow heap (frag case) to 33.606MB for 3214096-byte allocation
12-16 20:13:45.064    2778-2778/com.spekz D/MoPub﹕ Failed to retrieve GPS location: access appears to be disabled.
12-16 20:13:45.064    2778-2778/com.spekz D/MoPub﹕ Loading url:   http://ads.mopub.com/m/ad?v=6&id=47b3246cf9604036bfb1837d193d15d9&nv=3.3.0%2Bkit&dn=samsung%2CSM-G900F%2Ckltexx&udid=ifa%3A56d9b230-e477-4a7d-904a-5bf30f1ea0e1&z=%2B0100&o=p&sc_a=3.0&mr=1&mcc=219&mnc=10&iso=hr&cn=HR%20VIP&ct=2&av=1.0&android_perms_ ext_storage=1&ts=1
12-16 20:13:45.064    2778-2778/com.spekz I/MoPub﹕ Fetching ad for task #0
12-16 20:13:45.064    2778-2778/com.spekz I/com.mopub﹕ Fetching ad for task #0
12-16 20:13:45.364    2778-3261/com.spekz D/MoPub﹕ Loading ad type: admob_native
12-16 20:13:45.374    2778-3261/com.spekz I/System.out﹕ AsyncTask #4 calls detatch()
12-16 20:13:45.374    2778-2778/com.spekz D/MoPub﹕ Loading custom event adapter.
12-16 20:13:45.374    2778-2778/com.spekz D/MoPub﹕ Attempting to invoke custom event: com.mopub.mobileads.GooglePlayServicesBanner
12-16 20:13:45.374    2778-2778/com.spekz D/MoPub﹕ Couldn't locate or instantiate custom event: com.mopub.mobileads.GooglePlayServicesBanner.
12-16 20:13:45.374    2778-2778/com.spekz V/MoPub﹕ MoPubErrorCode: Unable to find Native Network or Custom Event adapter.
12-16 20:13:45.374    2778-2778/com.spekz D/MoPub﹕ Loading failover url: http://ads.mopub.com/m/ad?v=6&id=47b3246cf9604036bfb1837d193d15d9&nv=3.3.0%2Bkit&dn=samsung%2CSM-G900F%2Ckltexx&udid=ifa%3A56d9b230-e477-4a7d-904a-5bf30f1ea0e1&z=%2B0100&o=p&sc_a=3.0&mr=1&mcc=219&mnc=10&iso=hr&cn=HR%20VIP&ct=2&av=1.0&android_perms_ext_storage=1&ts=1&exclude=9fb97ef474b011e48e2c002590f2bb78&request_id=c9d0e74352be40218b76d719289e4c09&fail=1
12-16 20:13:45.374    2778-2778/com.spekz D/MoPub﹕ Loading url: http://ads.mopub.com/m/ad?v=6&id=47b3246cf9604036bfb1837d193d15d9&nv=3.3.0%2Bkit&dn=samsung%2CSM-G900F%2Ckltexx&udid=ifa%3A56d9b230-e477-4a7d-904a-5bf30f1ea0e1&z=%2B0100&o=p&sc_a=3.0&mr=1&mcc=219&mnc=10&iso=hr&cn=HR%20VIP&ct=2&av=1.0&android_perms_ext_storage=1&ts=1&exclude=9fb97ef474b011e48e2c002590f2bb78&request_id=c9d0e74352be40218b76d719289e4c09&fail=1
12-16 20:13:45.374    2778-2778/com.spekz I/MoPub﹕ Fetching ad for task #1
12-16 20:13:45.374    2778-2778/com.spekz I/com.mopub﹕ Fetching ad for task #1
12-16 20:13:45.674    2778-2849/com.spekz D/MoPub﹕ No ads found for adunit (47b3246cf9604036bfb1837d193d15d9).
12-16 20:13:45.674    2778-2849/com.spekz I/System.out﹕ AsyncTask #3 calls detatch()
12-16 20:13:45.684    2778-2778/com.spekz I/MoPub﹕ Ad failed to load.
12-16 20:13:45.684    2778-2778/com.spekz I/com.mopub﹕ Ad failed to load.
12-16 20:14:45.354    2778-2778/com.spekz D/MoPub﹕ Refresh disabled for ad unit (47b3246cf9604036bfb1837d193d15d9).
```

The app is not on any store, I am simply testing it on my phone. Does this make any difference?
Any help is greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 3):

It says:

> 12-16 20:13:45.374    2778-2778/com.spekz D/MoPub﹕ Couldn't locate or
>   instantiate custom event:
>   com.mopub.mobileads.GooglePlayServicesBanner.

This means it is likely that you have not integrated the adapter or there is an issue with the MoPub SDK accessing this file. The adapter is located here in the Android master SDK:
https://github.com/mopub/mopub-android-sdk/tree/master/extras/src/com/mopub/mobileads

Please reference the third party network integration documentation on steps to integrate the AdMob adapter and the corresponding AdMob SDK (use the latest version to be iOS8 compatible):
https://github.com/mopub/mopub-android-sdk/wiki/Integrating-Third-Party-Ad-Networks

It also seems that AdMob is not active on your ad unit. Please follow these steps to enable a network on an ad unit.

> 1. Go to the "Networks" tab in the MoPub UI
> 2. Click "Segments"
> 3. Click the specified segment you want to set (Note: Accounts will
>      automatically be set with a Global Segment on creation. This would
>      be the segment most people would need to navigate to to set the ad
>      network for the specific ad unit. This changes if a new segment is
>      created and has specific targeting as new segments will override the
>      Global Segment for their specific parameters.)
> 4. There is a filter set to show only running ad sources. You want to
>      close the tab for this that says "Status:Running" inside the filter
>      box to see the rest of the ad sources.
> 5. Click the drop down for the ad unit you want to change
> 6. Edit the ecpm of the ad source
> 7. Click "Set"
>
> This will enable the ad network for that specific ad unit.

https://twittercommunity.com/t/i-created-a-new-ad-unit-but-cant-target-my-ad-network-to-it-how-do-i-do-so/6927/2

Hope this helped!

Comment: This is one of the worst UIs I have seen in my life

Answer (score 1):

You need to integrate Google Play Services to your Mopub SDK if you are using AdMob. See more info here: https://github.com/mopub/mopub-android-sdk/wiki/Integrating-with-Google-Play-Services