# mopub banner ad is not displaying in android using android studio

Tags: android, mopub, android-studio-2.2

gradle`i imported`mopub SDK`i refereed this link [ref link][1] first one`jCenter AAR`after that i added code in`manifest.xml` also but still the banner is not loaded i am getting error like

```
    D/MoPub: Attempting to invoke custom event: com.mopub.mobileads.GooglePlayServicesBanner
D/MoPub: Couldn't locate or instantiate custom event: com.mopub.mobileads.GooglePlayServicesBanner.
V/MoPub: MoPubErrorCode: Unable to find Native Network or Custom Event adapter
```

i searched in google i got solution to add like this `The banner and interstitial adapters (e.g. GooglePlayServicesBanner.java and GooglePlayServicesInterstitial.java) should be placed in the com/mopub/mobileads folder in the MoPub SDK` 
but i am using android studio `gradle` lib so how to use it can any one help me.

Comment: have you tried this ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27512380/not-able-to-get-ads-from-admob-with-mopub

Comment: yes i tried after that i am getting this error before that i didn't get any error but i will get call back from onBannerFailed.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to place the file in com/mopub/mobileads. You can place it in your src folder with package name com.mopub.mobileads. (make sure you have moved the file to your app project, not in 'extras' folder)